# Java - Incorrect Reader

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, reader

I´m trying to read a txt file that contains special characters, but some of those characters are read as squares.

Here the code.

```
package reader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("cfg.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while( (line=reader.readLine()) != null ){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

The file:

```
ÉCltTctocsWicÉ#V^ÊûJö=
```

The console output:

```
�CltTctocsWic�#V^��J�=
```

The project is using UTF-8. Already tried FileInputStream with same result.

Do i need another reader?

**EDIT:Solved**

Thanks to @shmosel, the text file wasn't in UTF-8.
Thanks to @ACV, the InputStreamReader was necessary.

Here the new code:

```
public class Reader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("cfg.txt");

        /*to write*/
        BufferedWriter ou = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(file),"UTF8"));
        ou.append("ÉCltTctocsWicÉ#V^ÊûJö=");
        ou.close();

        /*to read*/
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
        String line;
        while( (line=in.readLine()) != null ){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the first version? Is the file actually saved in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
```

So basically UTF-8 files have to be read like binary files - using FileInputStream

Comment: @EJP "FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader." this is from javadoc for FileInputStream: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html